# using position numbers in str.format()

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I’m working on converting the use of % to str.format() and have become aware of the string not needing the positional numbers. For example

```
>>> "We have {0} hectares planted to {1}.".format(49, "okra")
'We have 49 hectares planted to okra.'
>>> "We have {} hectares planted to {}.".format(49, "okra")
'We have 49 hectares planted to okra.'
```

When should the numbers be used and when should they be omitted? If there’s only one substitution which way is clearer? In my entire script there are never substitutions out of order so I could be consistent using no numbers.

I am writing the script for scientists who do not often have programming knowledge, but often need to use/tweak the script a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Use the numbers when you are using the positional parameters out of order, more than once, or you need to support Python 2.6; the latter doesn't support auto-numbering of placeholders.

When your placeholders and positional parameters match exactly, the auto-numbering makes writing up a quick format that little bit easier.

Of course, if you feel there are too many parameters being passed in to easily count out where what parameter goes, you should manually number, or better still, use keyword arguments instead (mapping names to arguments is much easier to track). *Too many* is subjective, but I'd say [7 is the absolute maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two#The_.22magical_number_7.22_and_working_memory_capacity), with 5 or fewer being preferable.

Comment: I’d add to that that you should use numbers as soon as you have more than *<magic number>* arguments. Choose the magic number according to what you believe becomes difficult to read once the format string reaches a certain complexity.

Comment: @poke: For most humans I think the magic number is 7 (that's [how many distinct items or groupings your short-term memory can usually track](http://www.simplypsychology.org/short-term-memory.html)). By which time I'd have switched to using named slots, really.

Answer (score 2):

to be honest I think the best form of this would be

```
"We have {number} hectares planted to {what}.".format(number=5,what="Okra")
```

since this is very very readable

this answer is primarily opinion based I know...